# How do I manually check if Time Service is advertising or not?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

Server 2012 R2, Hyper-V VM-PDC w/AD DS, DNS

I originally had an Event ID 12 and successfully setup the time service as covered in this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/704219/how-do-i-confirm-what-my-pdc-is-using-for-its-time-source-and-how-do-i-setup-an).  The Event ID 12 no longer shows up during startups.  However, I am now seeing Event ID 144 which repeats from time to time saying

```
The time service has stopped advertising as a good time source
```

So does the time service re-advertise as good, or is it 'gone until fixed' once ID 144 shows up?

Hence my question, how do I check if the time service is advertising again?

Also, what causes it to stop advertising?  Is it just an inability to sync externally every now and then?  If I have to do something to fix this, where do I start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
nltest /dsgetdc:domain.com /server:dcname
```

Will have the TIMESERV flag if it is advertising.

You probably need to run:

```
w32tm /query /status /verbose /computer:dcname
```

To get more information about the problem.  Potential causes include it may be synchronizing from the hardware/cmos clock, or using the time synchronization of the Hyper-V integration services.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/virtual_active_directory_domain_controller_virtualization_hyperv%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: Perfect, Thx.  The TIMESERV flag was in fact present.  Good tip on the more extensive status command.  It showed that everything is working and the time source I selected is being used.  Had already read the Hyper-V link, but good to have listed here.  Cheers.